# Browser displayed different value for a large number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need display large number via binding in angularjs. Example is in [jsfiddle][1].

I want to display for example number 1175439502743699460, but browser displayed different value - 1175439502743699500 in Firefox, Opera and Chrome, 1175439502743699400 in IE. If I store number as string, it's displayed correctly.

```
    $scope.data = { 
                "longValue":1175439502743699460,
                "stringValue":"1175439502743699460"
              };
```

It's some way how display large number correctly without sending as string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Example:_Using_Number_to_convert_a_Date_object

```
var biggestInt = 9007199254740992;
var smallestInt = -9007199254740992;
```

Comment: So it's no way to display my large number as number and I must work with them as with string. Thanks

Comment: You can use floats but maybe that's not what you want either.